# Ruby - Custom Marker with Logo (Google Maps)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hi to the person/s that can help.

At the moment, I'm working on Google Maps that will have multiple markers but each marker will be unique with a company logo in situ. The background of the marker will be the same all the time.

Below is a quick mock-up on how the markers should look
[image: Below is a quick mock-up on how the markers should look]

Basics:

1. Same background
2. Unique logo per company (note will have plenty of companies)
3. The company logo with loaded in a square shape, and will fall behind the blue marker(so don't mind certain parts of the logo to be hidden)

Ruby code

Showing the map marker in the map.html.erb

```
 var location = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i]['latitude'], data[i]['longitude'])
 bounds.extend(location);

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: location,
map: map,
icon:data[i]['image'],
url:data[i]['link']
  });
```

Controller.rb that calls the data

```
  def search
    @collection =  @tours.map do |t|
        {"name"=>t.host.company_name,"latitude"=>t.host.latitude,"longitude"=>t.host.longitude,"image"=>t.host.company_logo.url(:thumb),"link"=>host_show_path(t.host.id)}.to_json if t.host.latitude.present? && t.host.longitude.present?
    end
```

The map is working and already pulling the company (host) logo which displays.

Now it is only to get the generic background.

Hope someone can help, and not sure what way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You can use rmagick gem to generate the required image using the 2 images.

Comment: @Sajin thanks for sharing this although not sure where to start, and will look for tutorials